# stochastic dominance definition

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I was wondering if, for positive random variables $X$ and $Y$, $\Pr(X\geq Y)\geq 1/2$ implies $\Pr(X\geq x)\geq \Pr(Y\geq x)$. Intuitively it "makes sense", since $X$ tends to be more often bigger than $Y$, hence for a fixed $x$, $Y$ is dominated by $X$. If this is true, then to check stochastic dominance it might in some cases be easier to verify the ordering.

If this is not correct, in general then are there conditions we may place on the random variables to cast this true?

Comment: Consider independent $X$ and $Y$ s.t. $\Pr(X = 1) = 1/4$, $\Pr(X = 2) = 3/4$, $\Pr(Y = 1) = \Pr(Y = 2) = \Pr(Y = 3) = 1/3$. $\Pr(X \geq Y) = 7/12 > 1/2$, but $\Pr(X \geq 3) = 0 < \Pr(Y \geq 3) = 1/3$.

Comment: This is an excellent and nice example. A similar suggestion was also made by d.k.o. below.

Comment: This issue is studied in Wrather and Yu, "Probability Dominance in Random Outcome", *Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications, vol. 36, 1982. They define $\beta$-dominance by $P (X > Y) \ge \beta$, for $\beta \ge 1/2$.

Comment: @mlc manyt hanks for the nice reference!

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following example: $\mathsf{P}(Y=1)=1$, $\mathsf{P}(X=0)=1/3$, and $\mathsf{P}(X=2)=2/3$. Here,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X\ge Y)=\frac{2}{3}.
$$
However,
$$
\frac{1}{3}=\mathsf{P}\!\left(X\le\frac{1}{2}\right)\ge \mathsf{P}\!\left(Y\le\frac{1}{2}\right)=0.
$$

Comment: This is a nice example :-) thanks a lot +1. But then can we place some conditions on the random variables so that this holds?

Comment: @Math-fun: It's easy to do the reverse exercise :) Given distributions $G$ and  $F$.s.t. $F\ge G$ you can construct $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\sim G$ and $Y\sim F$ and $P\{X\ge Y\}\ge \alpha$...

Comment: This is for sure, thanks again of course :-)